STM32F412 SDIO Tx Underrun error when DMA is enabled
I am working on a project where I have to drive a SD Card. So far I have successfully implemented the initialization and reading data with DMA part. I am not using HAL libraries. The code to write to external flash is shown below. I did everything according to reference manual.
void SDIO_MEM_Write_SingleBlock512(uint32_t Address, uint32_t* Buffer)
{
    //Single Block Transfer

    //uint8_t Result = 0xFF;
    uint8_t tempCardState;

    SDIO->DLEN = 512;
    SDIO->DTIMER = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    //Configure DMA
    DMA2->LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF3 | DMA_LIFCR_CHTIF3 | DMA_LIFCR_CTEIF3 | DMA_LIFCR_CFEIF3; //Clear Interrupt Flag

    DMA2_Stream3->CR = 0;
    DMA2_Stream3->CR |= (0b11 << DMA_SxCR_PL_Pos) | DMA_SxCR_MINC | (0b01 << DMA_SxCR_DIR_Pos) | (4 << DMA_SxCR_CHSEL_Pos) | (0b01<<DMA_SxCR_MBURST_Pos) | (0b01<<DMA_SxCR_PBURST_Pos) | (0b10 << DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_Pos) | (0b10 << DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_Pos) | (0b1<<DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_Pos);
    DMA2_Stream3->PAR  = (uint32_t) &SDIO->FIFO;
    DMA2_Stream3->M0AR = (uint32_t) Buffer; //Memory Address which data will be copied
    DMA2_Stream3->NDTR = 128; // Data to be transfered
    DMA2_Stream3->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

    //Write Single Block Command issued by using CMD24
    SDIO_SendCMD(Address, 24, WAIT_SHRTRESPONS, 0);

    if(SDIO_WaitCMDResponse() != 0xFF)
    {
        while(1);//Error Occurred
    }

    //Get R1 for Analysis
    if((SDIO->RESP1) & 0xFDFFE008) //Card Status
    {
        while(1);//Error Occurred
    }


    SDIO->DCTRL = 0;
    SDIO->DCTRL |= ((BLKSIZE_512 << SDIO_DCTRL_DBLOCKSIZE_Pos) | (TRSFRDIR_HtC << SDIO_DCTRL_DTDIR_Pos) | (TRSFRMOD_BLK << SDIO_DCTRL_DTMODE_Pos) | SDIO_DCTRL_DTEN | SDIO_DCTRL_DMAEN);

    while((SDIO->STA & (SDIO_STA_DBCKEND)) == 0);

    SDIO->ICR = (SDIO_ICR_DBCKENDC | SDIO_ICR_DATAENDC);

    //Wait until write Operation is finished
    do
    {
        if(SDIO_FetchCardState(&tempCardState) != 0xFF)
        {
            while(1);//Error Occurred
        }
    }while(tempCardState == 0x04); //Check Transfer State

    //return Result;
}




The problem is as soon as I enable DMA and SDIO ( SDIO->DCTRL |= ((BLKSIZE_512 << SDIO_DCTRL_DBLOCKSIZE_Pos) | (TRSFRDIR_HtC << SDIO_DCTRL_DTDIR_Pos) | (TRSFRMOD_BLK << SDIO_DCTRL_DTMODE_Pos) | SDIO_DCTRL_DTEN | SDIO_DCTRL_DMAEN);) I get Tx FIFO underrun error in SDIO STA register and FIFO error in DMA ISR register. I changed the order of enabling DMA/SDIO but nothing seems to work.
Has anyone encountered this problem?
